# How to NOT pack a C# source generator and NOT upload it to NuGet?

Tags: c#, nuget, csharp-source-generator

I created a class library and uploaded it to NuGet.org.
The class library uses a C# source generator to generate repetitive code (e.g. methods using value tuples).

The class library lives a happy life on NuGet.org, but, somehow, the source generator project got packaged and uploaded as well, which isn't what I wanted...

How to **prevent** a source generator project from being uploaded to NuGet?

---

The `.csproj` of the class library:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- Version, Authors, Description and other NuGet package info abbreviated here. -->
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference
         Include="..\MyLib.SourceGenerators\MyLib.SourceGenerators.csproj"
         OutputItemType="Analyzer"
         ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"/>
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The `.csproj` of the source generator:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
      <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.8.0"/>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.2">
         <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
         <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>` to the `.csproj` of the source generator project seems to prevent a NuGet package from being generated, similar to unit test projects.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
      <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
      <IsPackable>false</IsPackable> <!-- HERE -->
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.8.0"/>
      <!-- ... -->
```